# Radio Button List Layout ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, css, radiobuttonlist

I'm having trouble achieving desired layout for radiobuttonlist. I want the output to look like the image below.

Here is a link to what I'm trying to achieve:

http://skitch.com/hiraldesai/fcfn9/radio-button-layout

Here is my code trying to achieve the above, but I am not able to get the text above the radio button programmatically. Is it a CSS thing? I have tried many different combinations of RepeatLayout, RepeatDirection, RepeatColumns, TextAlign, etc.

```
AnswerRadioButtons.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Table
AnswerRadioButtons.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal
```

Thanks for advising.

Comment: the image in the question is broken now, however the answer is useful anyway

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to do it with this test.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
        RepeatLayout="Table" CssClass="RBL" TextAlign="Left">
    <asp:ListItem Text="radio button 1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="radio button 1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="radio button 1" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

With this css

```
.RBL label
{
    display: block;
}

.RBL td
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: And vertical-align: bottom; for the .RBL td style